# Determining the default() value of a class in C#

Tags: c#, default-value, msdn, xelement

MSDN's documentation on standard C# classes doesn't seem to contain what the `default` value for that type is. Am I not looking in the right place? Specifically, I am trying to figure out what the `default` value of `XElement` is.

I can always run my program and figure it out then, but I'd like a way to avoid that, if possible.

**Edit:** [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) shows the default values for the native types, but I'm wondering about complex types.

Comment: [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xwth0h0d.aspx): "will return null for reference types and zero for numeric value types. For structs, it will return each member of the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are value or reference types"

Comment: I'd expect it to be `null`. Can't you just try this yourself? `var foo = default(XElement);` and check what `foo` is?

Comment: @DanielKelley: I was looking for a means of doing it without executing any code. But the answer ended up being simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *default* value for all reference types is *null*.As stated in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx):

> The solution is to use the *default* keyword, which will return `null` for reference types and zero for numeric value types.